# Is there a canonical way to get data from a parent in the containment tree?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

I have an actionscript-instantiated component in a containment hierarchy; it extends ComboBox, but it's instantiated dynamically--you never know when you're going to need it.

Somewhere up in its containment hierarchy, there's a thing which extends NavigatorContent which logically is the right place to put the valid values for said combo box.

What's the canonical way for that child component to get a reference to that set of valid values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would solve this by having the child dispatch a bubbling event (CHILD_CREATED) with a self refrence when it's created. Then simply listen for the CHILD_CREATED event in the object that has access to the set of valid values.

**#1** Parent is created - add a listener to know when a child is created and needs a refrence to values

**#2** Child is created - dispatches CHILD_CREATED dynamic event with a self refrence as a property

**#3** Parent hears CHILD_CREATED - extracts the reference to the child component and sets its data provider to the set of valid values.

**EDIT:**

A much cleaner way to handle this kind of problem if you are dealing with a component based on DataGroup is to use the [rendererAdd](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/DataGroup.html#event%3arendererAdd) (there is a refrence to the renderer in the event). **This would definitly be the canonical way to handle it**.

So if you are using a DataGroup to display components that you need to access directly, just use the rendererAdd event. If that issn't applicable to your problem, I'd go with the CHILD_CREATED method.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is one canonical way to solve this.  There are so many possible solutions. You could:

- Pass the values as an argument to the child constructor
- Pass a reference to the NavigatorContent and then get the values directly upon instantiation
- Pass a reference to the NavigatorContent and then add a change listener to it, which fires every time a new value is set
- Use a Factory or Factory Method which has a reference to the NavigatorContent to create and populate the child
- Create a Proxy or Delegate class to manage creation and data population of all children of the NavigatorContent
- ...

I'm sure there are tons more.

It all depends on what your program is doing, how the rest of the hierarchy works together, when and if those values are updated, and whatever other requirements need to be fulfilled.
Start from there, then look at the suggestions people have made here, and pick one which suits your scenario best.

Comment: The reason this doesn't work in the general case is you basically have to pass any information you want down the entire tree of dynamically-created components, "just in case" a component needs the data. Haemp's answer provides a mechanism that allows the client to ask the parent(s) for the data it needs. FWIW, my initial naive solution was to walk up the containment tree looking for the class I knew had the data.  That's quick and dirty, does the job, and lacks any sort of elegance whatsoever.  It also breaks encapsulation severely.

Comment: Having a Factory create the elements would not require passing arguments down the containment tree, nor would it break encapsulation: You would create a CreationManager singleton which contains a reference to the NavigatorContent, then use CreationMananager.instance.getComboBoxFactory().createComboBox() wherever you need one.  You would not rely on the display list, nor would it require the NavigatorContent to know how to handle which kind of child. How does that not work in general?